I am always impressed with the usage of "Having said that" in speaking
I would like to know how this can be used in communication at different levels(Beginner/Intermediate/Advanced)

Look it up. And have a look at the answer here.

You want to use it because your are impressed by its usage? What impresses you about it? Why? And in what sense does being impressed by its usage (bu others) constitute a reason to use it yourself?

What is the question? Please put the question details in the full text, the title should just be a short summary.

It's functionally identical to "however" as a conjunction, i. e. as a way to introduce a qualification to a preceding statement.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENHVQ2gslp8

Thank you. That is very clear
